# Authentication error when deploying site's content

Tags: 7, deployment

I have two sites *site01* and *site02* each having some content (book pages) in them. I want to copy the content of *site01* to *site02* without overwriting its existing content.
I am using [Deploy](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) module to do this, by following [this procedure](http://drupal.org/node/1406134).
Everything is OK until I click "Deploy" on *site01*. When I do I get the following error:[image: snap]
I see that someone else got a [similar error](http://drupal.org/node/1535258), but I was not able to understand the solution applied by the person. Does anybody have any clue about this?

**UPDATE**
I tried same scenario using two different machines in LAN, and it worked fine! I was able to do the deployment smoothly.
But, on same server it is failing. I don't know what may be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is causing the problem when the sites are on local server i.e. `http://localhost`, but it works as expected if the sites are on different servers (could be in LAN).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that on this step:

> For Endpoint URL, enter
>   'http://your-destination-site.example.com/services/rest'. Click
>   'Finish'. Note that it appears that any path other than
>   '/services/rest' on either origin or destination generates a Request
>   response error: -1002 missing schema.

Your entering the incorrect url. Make sure you are using clean url's. If not, make sure to include the "?q=" part for the path.