# DeployAuthenticationException: Authentication error when try to push the content

Tags: 7, users, services, deployment

I have two sites on my localhost registration and testing. I want to push the content (node having type article) from testing to registration.I am using Deploy module to do this, by following this procedure.
"https://www.drupal.org/node/1406134"

Everything is OK until I click "Deploy" on testing. When I do I get the following error:

[image]

my path to endpoint is "/services/rest. and I also visit here
[Authentication error when deploying site's content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35221/authentication-error-when-deploying-sites-content)

but my issue still open.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I solving applying this patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/2017767#comment-7773329

Hope it helps!