# How do I debug connection problems while testing Deploy module while using local host?

Tags: 7, deployment

I'm attempting to properly set up between the [Deploy Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) between these two by follow [these instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1406134). I've used [Drush QuickDrupal](https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/core-quick-drupal/) to set up two new Drupal 7 instances.

```
$ drush qd d7-deploy-stage
$ drush qd d7-deploy-live
```

Initially, I ran them as on the same host machine via PHP's internal development server

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 # d7-deploy-stage
$ php -S localhost:9000 # d7-deploy-live
```

The end point is listed as `http://localhost:9000/services/rest` and the authentication (and only user) is `admin` with password of `admin`.

However upon a `cron run` on the d7-deploy-stage instance I

> DeployAuthenticationException: Authentication error:-111 Connection refused in DeployAuthenticatorSession->deploy()

**Question(s):** How would I begin to debug this? Since the error reads "connection refused", I'm also curious if I start the servers with a fully qualified domain name (or my machine's IP) or if the port numbers an issue in the addressing

**What I've tried so far:**

*The Patch:*
The '[#31](https://www.drupal.org/node/2017767#comment-7773329)' has failed with the following output `patch -p1 < deploy-404_CSRF_error-2017767-31.patch`

> patching file plugins/DeployAuthenticatorSession.inc Hunk #1 FAILED at
>   76. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file plugins/DeployAuthenticatorSession.inc.rej

**Update**

On both instances, based [this answer below](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/202045/5966), I downloaded the 'add start up .ht.route' patch, applied and restarted

```
wget https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/add_a_startup-1543858-58.patch
patch < add_a_startup-1543858-58.patch to each instance.
php -S public-ip-number:8000 .ht.router.php # stage
php -S public-ip-number:9000 .ht.router.php # live
```

The error on `drush cron` has changed

> WD deploy: DeployAuthenticationException: Authentication error: 404 Not found : Could not find resource user. in DeployAuthenticatorSession deploy() (line 76 modules/deploy/plugins/DeployAuthenticatorSession.inc).

Comment: Similar: [DeployAuthenticationException: Authentication error when try to push the content](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/127217/1908)

Comment: While that is a similar question, I've tried the patch with no luck. My question also asks a broader question in which I hope to see if my problem is inherit in the module or the testing infrastructure. That is, is my end point `localhost` with port number a bad idea? Is a FDQN a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your examples.

1. You're missing routing-script for the built-in PHP web server. It's recommended to use since you're using PHP built-in web server and by default it may have some problems handling certain clean URLs (for example URI containing dots are treated as direct files). So you should apply this patch from [#1543858](https://www.drupal.org/node/1543858) and re-run you server as below (same file you can use for both Drupal 7 & 8):

   ```
   php -S localhost:8000 .ht.router.php
   ```
2. You should use `-l` in order to specify URI of the Drupal site to use, so your code knows what's your proper hostname (since the fail is related to the connectivity issue).

   ```
   drush -v -l http://localhost:8000/ cron
   ```

If you still have *Connection refused*, you should check where the code is trying to connect and check the connection (e.g. wrong configuration or firewall in place). To debug the connectivity issue, on OS X you can use `dtruss`, on Linux this can be debugged by `strace`, e.g.

```
strace -e trace=network -fp $(pgrep -fn php)
```